# Why doesn’t transitivity of equals sign apply here?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

Consider the following proof in Linear Algebra Done Wrong.
[image]

The logic of the proof makes sense to me, but I don’t see why this proof is necessary over a shorter proof. That is, why doesn’t the equality of the representations follow from the transitivity of the equals sign? If representation 1 equals v, and representation 2 equals v, then it seems to me that representation 1 = representation 2 would follow from this in the same way that a=c follows from a=b and b=c. I take it this is invalid otherwise the author would’ve done it; but why is that?

Comment: Well, it is Linear Algebra "Done Wrong"

Comment: Presentation $1$ may equal presentation $2$, but that does not mean the **coefficients** are all equal. For example, we can express $1$ as $1=2(2) + 3(-1)$; and we can represent $1$ as $1=2(-1)+3(1)$. And we can indeed deduce that this means that $2(2)+3(-1) = 2(-1)+3(1)$. But what we actually want to conclude from this equality is that the numbers multiplying $2$ and $3$ in the two expressions are the same, and that does not follow.

Answer (score 2):

You’re putting too little emphasis on/misunderstanding the word ‘representation’. The statement being proved is the following:

> for all pairs of $n$-tuples of scalars $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ and $(\tilde{\alpha}_1,\dots,\tilde{\alpha}_n)$, we have $\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_kv_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\tilde{\alpha}_kv_k$ implies that $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)=(\tilde{\alpha}_1,\dots,\tilde{\alpha}_n)$.

It is this statement which we refer to as ‘equality/uniqueness of the representation of a given vector relative to the basis $\{v_1,\dots, v_k\}$’. We’re trying to prove the equality of the tuples of scalars. This is a non-trivial statement which requires a proof, and uses linear independence.

We are **not** trying to prove the following (trivial) statement:

> $\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_kv_k=v$ and $v=\sum_{k=1}^n\tilde{\alpha}_kv_k\implies \sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_kv_k=\sum_{k=1}^n\tilde{\alpha}_kv_k$.

This is indeed obvious, and is just transitivity of equality. But, like I said, this is not what is being proved.

Comment: I see, thank you. By the way would you mind telling me how you fit the symbolic notation into your response?

Comment: @Joa what do you mean?

Comment: The Greek letters, the sum notation, the conditional, etc. How did you type these into your answer?

Comment: oh you can right-click on the math, then click on “show math as >” and then click on “Tex commands”. Or if you say click on the edit button of my answer, you should be able to see the full code (though you may not have a high enough rep to do this?). Anyway, there should be an easy latex/mathjax tutorial on the site somewhere. A quick search should bring it up.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is similar to saying

If $a,b,c,d,e$ are real numbers, and

$$ a+b=c=d+e$$

Then

$$ a=d \land b=e $$

Clearly this isn't the case in general, since the "representation" of a vector is not the same as the vector itself, and it is entirely possible for a vector to have multiple distinct representations over a set that is not linearly independent (of course the sets in question *are* linearly independent, but you need to use that somehow in the proof, otherwise the proof would apply to sets of vectors which are not linearly independent, which we saw it doesn't with the above example)